# Draw circle on touch position and show the coordinates

Tags: java, android, canvas, imageview, point

I am doing a project like to draw circle on touch position and show the coordinates when touch on canvas. Exactly same like this http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-circle-at-the-touched-position-of-view-canvas/.. from the link, he use `PaintView` to draw the circle on it. My question is, can I simply change `PaintView` to the `ImageView`? And when I change, I got an error on passing reference of `ImageView` to update on coordinate change.It says `setTextView(TextView) is undefined for the type ImageView`.. how to solve that? I am new in android programming..Thanks for any answer.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Getting reference to ImageView
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imv1);

    // Getting reference to TextView tv_coordinate
    TextView tvCoordinates = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_coordinates);

    // Passing reference of textview to ImageView object to update on    coordinate changes
    imageView.setTextView(tvCoordinates); //error here

    // Setting touch event listener for the ImageView
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(imageView);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use ImageView.
ImageView is a kind of View which Android already provided.
(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)
For your purpose (draw circle on touch position and show the coordinates), ImageView cannot help.

this link http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-circle-at-the-touched-position-of-view-canvas/.., he use a custom View
You can use your own custom view same as his custom View

Comment: Thanks but I don't think I can use custom view because actually I want to draw circle on an image and show the coordinates. do u have any idea?

Comment: Still use above link: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-circle-at-the-touched-position-of-view-canvas/..

Just change one thing in the layout file

    <in.wptrafficanalyzer.graphicsdrawpointviewcanvas.PaintView
        android:id="@+id/paint_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/your_background_image"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_coordinates" />

Answer (score 0):

Still use above link: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-circle-at-the-touched-position-of-view-canvas/..

Just change one thing in the layout file

```
<in.wptrafficanalyzer.graphicsdrawpointviewcanvas.PaintView
    android:id="@+id/paint_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/your_background_image"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_coordinates" />
```

Comment: ya I also think the same way. but my image is from gallery. I can draw the circle on that image but it does not show the coordinates. the touch point are not show on the screen but only show in logcat .. for example; **point:22,28** .. sorry if my question is so complicated.

Comment: its ok. already got my solution by just removing that error part. lol